# Does prefetching a write ever affect single core performance?

Tags: x86-64, multicore, cpu-architecture, prefetch, cpu-cache

Some architectures have a "prefetch write" instruction to indicate to the CPU that you're going to be writing to a memory location before you actually do it. I understand that on a multicore machine this can be used by the core as a hint that it should try to get ownership of the given cache line now so that it can write to the location more quickly later. However, AFAICT that should only matter in situations when there are two cores potentially contending for the cache line. For a cache line that's only being read and written by a single core, does a prefetch write ever have any use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All else being equal, Prefetch-Write has no benefit over Prefetch-Read for lines accessed only by a single core.  After any kind of prefetch, the core will own the line in the **Exclusive** state.  On a subsequent write, the line changes to the **Modified** state.  An Exclusive-to-Modified transition is free since by definition no other core has the line.  The E->M state change completes locally without snooping.

Beware that cores have their own hardware prefetch logic.  An access to a line may cause the core to grab adjacent line(s) automatically.  If global variables or other data reside nearby, an SMP system may experience a lot of unexpected cross-snooping.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that it could help if the cache line isn't in memory and the write prefetch flags that it will be needed some cycles from now. Housekeeping chores such as freeing up a line for the write could be more out of the way. Surely this should allow the CPU to complete the write faster than if it simply unloaded a write out of the blue into the lap of the cache?

Or have I missed something fundamental?

Comment: So you're saying that because a write prefetch will also act like a normal prefetch, it might help? It's possible you are right.

Comment: Anything that goes between the CPU and RAM must do so via a cache line. If the cache line in question isn't loaded then the read or write will have to wait until it is.